# Is there a way to stop additional Javascript from running after a window.history.forward?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery file that gets loaded when the page is loaded.  The very first line is:

```
window.history.forward(1);
```

Later in the file, there are Ajax calls that I'd like to disable if the forward command is going to prevent the page from loading (preventing a back button load).

The Ajax calls actually fail in this situation (Chrome reports the error, IE and Firefox don't but they do make the callback).  Is there a way that I can get the status of the "forward" call and use it to gate the other calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could detect whether the forward call did anything is to just check the URL before/after.

In other words, you could do something like:

```
var currentUrl = window.location;
window.setTimeout(function(){
    if (window.location != currentUrl) return;
    // The rest of your code that you want to go off if the forward didn't work
}, 1000 *2); // wait 2 seconds
```

Comment: I don't think that I'd have ever come up with that one.  Thanks!